# sync tfs and subversion

Tags: svn

I am looking for a tool that can merge/sync changes between TFS 2012 and subversion. 
Is there a tool for this or do I have to do this manually? 
I assume this is not built in functionality in TFS 2012 or subversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, but you have nothing except [SVNBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on such a tool. Mostly for myself - my company switched to TFS 2010 and I prefer working with SVN. The main focus is continuous background synchronization, but probably can be used for migration too. Haven't tried with TFS 2012 yet.

Here is the link: http://ficusdev.com/SvnTfsSync